# Inserting Advance Custom Fields in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, advanced-custom-fields

I have a file called smart screen-front.php. Inside this file I am trying to output some php variables inside some javascript:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/javascript"); // This bit must come first!
?>
<?php $ssimage1 = get_field('smartscreen_slider_image_1'); ?>
<?php $ssimage2 = get_field('smartscreen_slider_image_2'); ?>
<?php $ssimage3 = get_field('smartscreen_slider_image_3'); ?>
<?php $ssimage4 = get_field('smartscreen_slider_image_4'); ?>
<?php $ssimage5 = get_field('smartscreen_slider_image_5'); ?>
<?php $ssimage6 = get_field('smartscreen_slider_image_6'); ?>
<?php $ssimage7 = get_field('smartscreen_slider_image_7'); ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(document).ready(function () {

            jQuery.supersized({

                // Functionality
                slide_interval          :   10000,      // Length between transitions
                transition              :   1,          // 0-None, 1-Fade, 2-Slide Top, 3-Slide Right, 4-Slide Bottom, 5-Slide Left, 6-Carousel Right, 7-Carousel Left
                transition_speed        :   1000,
                keyboard_nav            :   1,

                // Speed of transition

                // Components
                slide_links             :   'blank',    // Individual links for each slide (Options: false, 'num', 'name', 'blank')
                slides                  :   [           // Slideshow Images
                    {image : <?php echo $ssimage1; ?>, title : '<div class="slider-caption"><h2></h2><p></p></div>',  thumb : '', url : ''} ,
                    {image : <?php echo $ssimage2; ?>, title : '<div class="slider-caption"><h2></h2><p></p></div>', thumb : '', url : ''} ,
                    {image : <?php echo $ssimage3; ?>, title : '<div class="slider-caption"><h2></h2><p></p></div>', thumb : '', url : ''} ,
                    {image : <?php echo $ssimage4; ?>, title : '<div class="slider-caption"><h2></h2><p></p></div>',  thumb : '', url : ''} ,
                    {image : <?php echo $ssimage5; ?>, title : '<div class="slider-caption"><h2></h2><p></p></div>',  thumb : '', url : ''},
                    {image : <?php echo $ssimage6; ?>, title : '<div class="slider-caption"><h2></h2><p></p></div>',  thumb : '', url : ''} ,
                    {image : <?php echo $ssimage7; ?>, title : '<div class="slider-caption"><h2></h2><p></p></div>',  thumb : '', url : ''}

                    ]
            });
        }

);
</script>
```

This is not outputting the php variables. What am I doing wrong.

Comment: What happens if you just try to output those variables into a `<div/>`?  Are they being populated at all?

Comment: is your get_field() function has worked properly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you may need to wrap the `<?php echo ...; ?>` statements in the javascript in quotes:

```
'<?php echo ...; ?>'
```

or

```
"<?php echo ...; ?>"
```

As it stands now, assuming each `$ssimageX` contains a string looking something like `"X.jpg"`, the javascript ends up looking like

```
{image : X.jpg, title : '<div class="slider-caption"><h2></h2><p></p></div>',  thumb : '', url : ''}
```

Which would result in a `ReferenceError` unless `X` is defined, and could be a `SyntaxError` if the url has a `/` in it.

My guess is you want it to look more like

```
{image : 'X.jpg', title : '<div class="slider-caption"><h2></h2><p></p></div>',  thumb : '', url : ''}
```